# Как правильно тестировать код для разных версий MySQL?

Tags: mysql, юнит-тесты, тестирование, phpunit, codeception

У меня есть код, который имеет различный выходной результат в зависимости от версии `MySQL`. Как такой код тестировать?

Comment: Явно указывай версию mysql при запуске тестов и в зависимости от нее уже запскай те или иные тесты.

Comment: *Как такой код тестировать?* Иметь все необходимые версии сервера. Выполнять при подключении к СУБД проверку версии в приложении на соответствие, и принимать необходимые меры (менять коллекцию запросов, выдавать предупреждение и прекращать работу и т.п.).